# How to use sql simple query to insert data from different table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, named supplierlist and supplierdetail, each table has 4 columns, called "suppcode", "suppname", "suppdetail", and "supplogo". I want to insert into supplierlist using data from supplierdata.

Here is my SQL query

```
insert into supplierlist('csid', 'suppcode', 'suppname', 'suppdetail', 'supplogo') 
value ('$csid', (select 'suppcode', 'suppname', 'suppdetail', 'supplogo' from supplierdetail where suppcode='$suppcode'))
```

My query does not work. Should I use "select" for each column to insert?

Comment: is it sql server or MySQL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
insert into supplierlist(`csid`, `suppcode`, `suppname`, `suppdetail`, `supplogo`) 
select '$csid',`suppcode`, `suppname`, `suppdetail`, `supplogo` 
from supplierdetail 
where suppcode='$suppcode'
```

Comment: csid value not from table

Comment: Its a variable isn't it? well you can add variables in your select along with column names from a table, the result set will have the column values from the table and it will select the variable value too.

Comment: Also for column names use square brackets `[]` for sql server or back ticks ` for MySQL using single quotes will result query treating it as literal strings.

Comment: tq its work, i just know value from variable can use to select query :D